# Add Hidden Form Attributes Dependant on Radio Selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a complicated form which I am trying to simplify. I have 2 subscription options, 6 and twelve months. For the shopping cart backend, I need to pass along hidden attributes (subscription end date) dependant to which duration the user selects.

i.e. If a users selects 6 months then the hidden attirbute should include this php as the value

Does anyone know how to do this without JS? I can't use JS because I am using PHP.

```
<form action="#" method="post">

<input type="radio" name="name" value="Six Months">Six Months</input>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="Twelve Months">Twelve Months</input>

<!-- add this if Six Months radio is selected
 -->
<input type="hidden" name="sub_enddate" value="<?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime("+12 month +1 day")); ?>"></input>

<!-- add this if Six Months radio is selected
 -->
<input type="hidden" name="sub_enddate" value="<?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime("+6 month +1 day")); ?>"></input>

</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cNKkQ/

Comment: If you are trying to accomplish this with PHP only, you will have to submit the form when they make a radio selection. There is no way around that. Is that ok?

Comment: Why does your use of php stop you from using JS?

Comment: @mplungjan if I used JS then I would get the user agents time which isn't always that reliable nor secure from my end. DO you know of any ways to still use the php time stamp and achive my goal using JS?

Comment: @AnalogWeapon I don't think ill be able to do that. I am passing the form onto the ecommerce clients site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to submit the form twice if you don't want to use JavaScript. So:

```
<form action="#" method="post">

<input type="radio" name="subscriptionLength" value="Six Months">Six Months</input>
<input type="radio" name="subscriptionLength" value="Twelve Months">Twelve Months</input>

<?php
if ($_POST['subscriptionLength'] == "Six Months") {
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sub_enddate\" value=\"".date('Ymd', strtotime("+6 month +1 day"))."\"></input>";
} elseif ($_POST['subscriptionLength'] == "Twelve Months") {
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sub_enddate\" value=\"".date('Ymd', strtotime("+12 month +1 day"))."\"></input>";
}
?> 

</form>
```

Then you'll have to add a field to determine if they are submitting for the first or second time.

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpfull. I just tried it out and it doesn't seem to be working. What do you mean by submitting the form twice? Sorry for the ignorance, my PHP isn't good at all.

Answer (score 0):

> *Without JS*. But you need using JS here.

// Index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if ( (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post') && !empty($_POST['radio_month']) ){

        $sub_enddate = ($_POST['radio_month']== "Six Months" ) ? $_POST['sub_enddate_6'] : $_POST['sub_enddate_12'];
        /*
         TODO Choose

         $_SESSION['sub_enddate'] = $sub_enddate;
          or

         $_COOKIE['sub_enddate'] = $sub_enddate;
          or 

         $QUERY_STRING ='';
         $QUERY_STRING = '?'.http_bulid_query(array('sub_enddate'=>$sub_enddate));

        */
        header("Location:action.php".$QUERY_STRING);
    }
?>   


<form action="#" method="post">

 <input type="radio" name="radio_month" value="Six Months">Six Months</input>
 <input type="radio" name="radio_month" value="Twelve Months">Twelve Months</input>

 <input type="hidden" name="sub_enddate_12" value="<?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime("+12 month +1 day")); ?>"></input>

 <input type="hidden" name="sub_enddate_6" value="<?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime("+6 month +1 day")); ?>"></input>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />     

 </form>
```

Action.php

```
session_start();

// choosen by "passing" type

$sub_enddate  = $_SESSION['sub_enddate'];
// or 
$sub_enddate  = $_COOKIE['sub_enddate']; 
// or 
$sub_enddate  = $_GET['sub_enddate'];
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="<?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime("+6 month +1 day")); ?>">Six Months</input>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="<?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime("+12 month +1 day")); ?>">Twelve Months</input>
```

Using JS without using client time

```
window.onload=function() {
  var vals = ['<?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime("+6 month +1 day")); ?>',
     '<?php echo date('Ymd', strtotime("+12 month +1 day")); ?>']
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    this.sub_enddate.value=vals[this.elements["name"][0].checked?0:1]
  }
}
```

with this HTML

```
<form id="form1" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="name" value="Six Months">Six Months</input>
  <input type="radio" name="name" value="Twelve Months">Twelve Months</input>
  <input type="hidden" name="sub_enddate" value=""></input>
</form>
```

Comment: That would be the easiest option but the platform I am using requires that you pass along a name, price, and end-date field.